# Cache busting a web-based Javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, web, browser-cache

So, I'm currently building a web-based plugin. The plugin is integrated to a site by including a JS file, say, for instance, [www.example.com/widget.js](http://www.example.com/widget.js) is attached as a script tag in the customer sites. I need to cache bust this JS file when I have future updates.

I cannot use hashing in the name as the clients will have to reintegrate the plugin whenever there are updates. I cannot use versioning in the URL for the same reasons.
Any strategies for this could be done?

Comment: Can't you use the [ETag header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag)?

Comment: @viv have you found any solution to this?